# Redirect 404 Not Found page using PHP or .HTACCESS file

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a bad URL for example http://www.example.com:7080/download/?page=download , I want to redirect into http://www.example.com using either PHP or .HTACCESS file. I unable to do it. Please help me.

Comment: It's a bad idea to redirect 404 to the main page. You should implement a proper 404 error page with the correct headers. And then, if you really want to, put a timer on it like "Page not found, you'll be redirected to the homepage in 5seconds automatically or click here"

Comment: I have to second @HugoDelsing on this. My boss decided this would be a good idea a couple of years back so we implemented it. It only took two weeks before we started getting angry calls from clients who'd mistyped their links asking why their content was suddenly redirecting to our website. If you redirect to the home page, people quite simply won't know what's happened.

Comment: Actually this is very old link(http://www.example.com:7080/download/?page=download). The 404 Not found page shows, It's some extends to LiteSpeed Web server. I am not getting its possible or not to redirect. Because when I tried to resolve this, nothing is happening. I think its out of control from my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Using php, you can use this code for page redirect:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=="/download/?page=download")
{    
   header("Location: http://www.startonlinegames.com");
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be as simple as the following:

```
Redirect 301 :7080/download/?page=download   http://www.startonlinegames.com
```

301 Simply means a permanent redirection

If you wish to redirect all 404 errors to you homepage you can do so with the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Comment: I put above code in .HTACCESS file, but its not redirecting.

Comment: @mdzawaralam I may have misunderstood your question. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Still its not redirecting.

Answer (score -2):

Please try the below

```
redirect :7080/download/?page=download  http://www.startonlinegames.com
```

Comment: He doesnt want a single file to be redirected. He wants 404 (with this page as example) for missing pages redirected

Comment: I put above code in .HTACCESS file, but its not redirecting.